# In the solution of this problem, why choose the positive square root?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

I was solving the following problem:

> [image]

I made it but I got confused by something: I've obtained more solutions than I should. I went to see the solution in hope of clearing it up, the solution is:

> [image]

Now here is where I got confused:

> [image]

**QUESTION:** They assumed that $q_1 + q_2 \geq 0$, was that made out of mathematical convenience or choosing $q_1 + q_2 \geq 0$ has some physical meaning? It's not clear to me why choose the positive square root here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says right in the problem statement that the total charge is positive.

> Of the initial charges on the spheres, *with a positive net charge*, what was [...]

Comment: Ah, yes! I am more used to the expression "total charge" than "positive net charge".